# Why does Ubuntu drain my laptop battery so quickly?

Tags: drivers, power-management, laptop, battery

The clock will never say any more than 6 hours off a full charge, which is awful.  I installed tlp but after starting it each boot there is barely a change.  I heard it may have something to do with the graphics card (NVidia 950M) and the driver it uses but how do I fix this?  Right now, I believe it's using Bumblebee because it says GeForce Graphics Driver or something in Details.

Any ideas?

Comment: the Linux kernel is not vary optimized for laptop. I have the same same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your installation is not optimized for battery life. If your graphic card is always on, it consumes more power.

You could try these things:

- Make sure that you wont use only your nvidia dependend on you bios settings (Enable Optimus & Dynamic graphic card there)
- Make sure you have installed bbswitch
- Make sure bbswitch is configured correctly. ([ArchWiki - Bumblebee](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bumblebee#Power_management))

Then it should work. Also, if you are using resource-hungry applications, it is possible that your device automatically uses your nvidia.

---

You could also check, wether your cpu is running in "performance"-mode or "power-saving"-mode.

Comment: how do check what mode the CPU is in?

Comment: @MattJaccino This should be also checkable in your BIOS settings. Your CPU has to support different power-modes.

Comment: I couldnt find anything in my bios about any of this.  My laptop is an Acer Aspire E5-575